# WSO2 bearer token expiry time varies in the token generation POST request among different clients

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 access token generation process which leverages the endpoint exposed from the identity server. We have found for some of the API consumers the token gets generated with a very less expiration time which is breaking some of the automated API endpoint invocation going forward. We have checked the default expiration time the API 2.6.0 and it is set to 3600 but this does not reflect in the tokens being generated. Can someone suggest if we are missing on any obvious details.

Token generation script

```
   client_id = 'xxxxxx'
    client_secret = 'xxxx'
    identity_url = 'https://<domain_name>/token'
    try:
        url = identity_url
        payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        json_resp_identity = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret), headers = headers )
        return json_resp_identity.json()`

{'access_token': '3a4f1ea3-634c-34f1-ae85-0735e6b401ab', 'scope': 'am_application_scope default', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 33729697}

{'access_token': '3a4f1ea3-634c-34f1-ae85-0735e6b401ab', 'scope': 'am_application_scope default', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 33729667}
```

While this same logic is giving the following result for the consumer who has reported the issue.

```
{"access_token":"345713c8-2dd4-33c1-a62e-0ba4ab84adf2","scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":9}

{"access_token":"4c05d045-ef97-38d4-9737-e49e2ddd5899","scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":4}
```

Things work fine when the token is generated via market place store url by going to the application tab where we can set the token expiration time via the text box.

We have checked the timeout configuration in the identity server and the following is there on the timeout settings.

```
cd /data/wso2/wso2is-km-5.7.0/repository/conf/identity
grep AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod identity.xml

<AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3600</AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
<UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3600</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>

<TimestampSkew>0</TimestampSkew>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way WSO2 IS token issuance flow is working for opaque access tokens. When you send a token request it checks whether you already have an active access token for the same user-clientId-scope combination (user is not considered in client credentials grant type). If an active token is found, it just returns the existing token. That should be the scenario which you observed tokens with short expiry time.

As a solution, you can switch to JWT token type. Then you will get a new access token for each token request. Ref https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Generating+a+JWT+token+from+the+API+Store

But please note that; if you send multiple token requests for the same [user-]clientId-scope combination, the previous tokens will get revoked and only the token returned for the last request will be valid.